# MATLAB: Modulus Function for Summing Odd Integers

Tags: matlab, numbers, modulo

How would you use the modulus function to sum odd integers?

I was able to view the odd integers but couldn't sum them together.

Comment: You can just use indexing to get the odd integers and then use `sum`. Don't understand the over-complication with `mod`.

Comment: @Divakar: You read my mind :P

Comment: @rayryeng I do that to people :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you don't want to use the modulus function *to sum odd integers*, but you want to use the modulus function to *help you determine what is an odd integer* and sum only those numbers in your data set *that are odd integers*. If you read this at a first glance, this is confusing because it sounds like you want to use the modulus function *and the modulus function only* to sum values.

Let's say you have integers in a vector called `data`.  What you can do is if you want to check to see whether an integer is odd, you check to see if the remainder once you divide by 2 is 1 (i.e. `num mod 2 == 1`).  Recall the definition of an odd number.  This means that you can take any integer, and represent it such that you can find an integer `k` where the number can be represented as `2k + 1`.  Therefore, if you were to take the modulus of this number with 2 as the base, you would get 1 as the answer.  Bear in mind that this **does not apply** to negative numbers.

As such, these are the steps that I would suggest that you do:

1. Find all of the locations where the modulo function gives you 1.
2. Use these locations and sum up your data.

Here is the code I would use:

```
function sumOdd = sumOddNumbers(data)
%// Step #1
ind = mod(data, 2) == 1;

%// Step #2
sumOdd = sum(data(ind));
```

Here we are creating a function that will help us do that.  You specify `data` as input into your function, and the output (`sumOdd`) will contain the sum of the odd numbers.  As such, take this code and save it to a new `.m` file.  Also, make sure you call it `sumOddNumbers.m`.  Next, make sure you set your working directory to be where you have placed this file.

Let's do a quick example:

```
data = 1 : 10; %// Create an array going from 1 to 10
sumOdd = sumOddNumbers(data); %// Answer should be 25... why?
```

Now let's go through the function step by step and see why the answer is 25.

```
ind = mod(data, 2) == 1; %// Should give us an array s.t. [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
sumOdd = sum(data(ind)); %// Should sum over the following array [1 3 5 7 9] 
                         %// Answer is 25
```

Comment: okay i understand now. Thank you. I have one more question, how would it work with a user input?

Comment: That's easy.  Turn it into a function.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: +1 for the effort to give such a detalied explanation

Comment: @LuisMendo: Gracias / Grazie :)

Comment: @LuisMendo I would try to answer in Vietnamese, but that's way beyond my current knowledge :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: hahaah no need :) I see that you were willing to try :P.... and I'm very touched! Also, French is perfectly acceptable.